# Why would commenting out a line of code change whether a *previous* line of code is executed?

Tags: c#, .net-1.1

With this code:

```
    using (pbDialog = new pbDialogs())
    {
        ProgressBar = new frmProgress(this, false);
        ProgressBar.SetProgressLabelText("Inventory Data");
        MessageBox.Show("Set progress label text to Inventory data");
        typeProgress = (int) ProgressStates.ProgressQRY;

        ProgressBar.label1.Text += " (Receiving)";
        if (pbDialog != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("pbDialog is not null");
            //pbDialog.ShowDialog(ProgressBar, this);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("pbDialog IS null");
            ProgressBar.ShowDialog();
        }

        ProgressBar = null;

        MessageBox.Show("Made it to compressDB()");
        compressDB();
        . . .
     }
```

I see "*Set progress label text to Inventory data*"
then "*pbDialog is not null*"
then "*Made it to compressDB()*"

Nothing too odd there; but if I uncomment the line that is commented above, I see only "*pbDialog is not null*"

It is hanging for some reason as a result to the call to ShowDialog(); what is really strange, though, is that this prevents "*Set progress label text to Inventory data*" from displaying. Why would that be the case?

Note: I think the "pb" in the code stands for "peanut brittle" or some such; I'm pretty sure about the "brittle" part, anyway.

### UPDATE

Yeah, the use of ShowDialog() with pbDialog is one of scads of examples that the original coder was practicing job security by obscurity - but then he [un]fortunately skedaddled, leaving in his wake a cesspool of spaghetti/eggshell code with no comments, misleading names and every sort of bizarre and convoluted, counterintuitive practice imaginable in the witches brew he purportedly considered a masterpiece of elegant design and clever-clever tricks.

pbDialog is an instance of a class (pbDialogs). Just to give you a taste of how macabre and convoluted and tangled it all is, here is that class:

```
public class pbDialogs : IDisposable
{
    private static Form m_top;

    public pbDialogs()
    {
    } // pbDialogs Constructor


    public static void Activate( Form form )
    {
        form.Capture = true;
        IntPtr hwnd  = OpenNETCF.Win32.Win32Window.GetCapture();
        form.Capture = false;
        OpenNETCF.Win32.Win32Window.SetForegroundWindow( hwnd );
    } // Activate

    /// <summary>
    /// This method makes ShowDialog work the way I want, I think.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Here is what it does:
    ///   1.  Sets the caption of the new window to the same as the caller's.
    ///   2.  Clears the caption of the parent so it won't show up in the task list.
    ///   3.  When the ShowDialog call returns, brings the previous window
    ///       back to the foreground.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="dialog"></param>
    /// <param name="parent"></param>
    public void ShowDialog( Form dialog, Control parent )
    {
        Control top    = parent.TopLevelControl;
        string caption = top.Text;
        dialog.Text    = caption;
        top.Text       = "--pending--";                 // Don't show parent in task list
        dialog.Activated += new EventHandler( form_Activated );
        dialog.Closed    += new EventHandler( form_Closed );
        m_top = dialog;                         // New top-most form
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        m_top = (Form)top;                      // The top dialog just changed
        dialog.Activated -= new EventHandler( form_Activated );
        dialog.Closed    -= new EventHandler( form_Closed );
        top.Text = caption;                     // Make visible in task list again
        Activate( (Form)top );                  // And make it the active window
    } // ShowDialog

    /// <summary>
    /// If one of our other windows, such as the main window, 
    /// receives an activate event, it will activate the current 
    /// top-most window instead.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private static void form_Activated( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        if( (m_top != null) && !(sender == m_top) ) // Is this the top-most window?
            Activate( m_top );                      // No, activate the top dialog
    } // form_Activated

    private static void form_Closed( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        m_top = null;               // When you close the top dialog, it's not top anymore
    } // form_Closed

    #region IDisposable Members
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // TODO:  Add pbDialogs.Dispose implementation
    }
    #endregion
} // class pbDialogs
```

There is also a "related" ProgressBar -- a form which shares a file with pbDialogs, and whose instance variable is defined in the file that contains the code above thusly:

```
public static frmProgress ProgressBar;
```

This is definitely "whack-a-mole" code - if I make one small, seemingly innocuous change, all Dallas breaks loose in what even a semi-sane person would consider a completely unrelated part of the code.

This may be an indication of just how squirrelly this code/project is: I will make a new build after commenting out a couple of lines, and the size of the file will change from 400KB to 408, or from 412 to 408, etc. It's not normal behavior for an .exe to change that much in size (in a relative sense) with such a small change, is it?

### UPATE 2

This, in frmProgress (which has both "public class frmProgress : System.Windows.Forms.Form" and "public class pbDialogs : IDisposable") scares me:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms;
```

The second (OpenNETCF) is grayed out, indicating it's not really used, but it may be that it was previously used, and somehow that "Windows.Forms" code inadvertently got switched to "System" code, and that may be contributing to its current groundsquirellyness.

Comment: Is it Debug or Release code?

Comment: It seems like the `pbDialog` is probably awaiting some sort of input before the code will continue.  But it IS odd that it would prevent the previous `MessageBox` from showing...

Comment: What exactly is `pbDialog`? The standard Form.ShowDialog doesn't have that signature (It can either take one parameter or none).

Comment: @Matt Seiker: I answer your question in a rather long-winded, exasperated and admittedly snarky way above.

Comment: @Evan: This code worked in the past (albeit it is very shaky, like a toddler-constructed tower of alphabet blocks).

Comment: @ClayShannon OpenNetCF... is this a Windows Mobile App? Also, unless you really need the (non-standard) behavior that `ShowDialog` method provides, I would get rid of it, calling `this.ShowDialog()` in the parent form. Heck, I would dump this whole class, it only creates unexpected behavior (and has who-knows-what interactions with MessageBox's, since those both stop the windows message pump on that form, I believe)

Comment: @MattSieker: Yes, it is - using .NET1-1 (don't get me started).

Comment: @ClayShannon Windows Mobile (I'm assuming if this is framework 1.1, that it could very well be PocketPC 2003 or so), can be quite picky about dealing with windows. All the more reason to ditch (or gut) this class. If you want the caption behavior, I would create a class based off Form that then adds a method that changes the title, shows the modal, and then changes it back, then any form that needs this behavior derives from your new Form class.

Comment: This is like trying to play Beethoven's "Fuer Elise" or Mendelsohn's Lullaby on the piano while wearing boxing gloves.

Answer (score 3):

`ShowDialog` is generally a blocking call.  The code will not continue past this until the dialog is closed.